# Jquery refresh is creating an unwanted infinite loop

Tags: jquery, infinite-loop

I have a buddy list that is set to refresh. After every refresh is then begins adding the same names to the list instead of just refreshing the function. Any ideas would be great or maybe I have just missed something complete?

```
$(function() {

$('<div />').html('<div id="buddies" class="buddies" style="vertical-align:bottom"><div class="imheader">&nbsp;Online Favorites<span class="fr"><a href="#" id="exitlist">X</a></span></div><div class="imheader2"><div class="imheaderspan"><a href="#">Options</a></div></div><ul class="imwindow"><div id="myonlinefavs"></div></ul></div><div id="chatbar" class="chatbar"><div id="ims"></div><div class="buddylist" id="buddylist"><center><a href="#" id="im-menu" class="im-menu">Favorites (<strong id="friendsonline">0</strong>)</a></center></div></div>').appendTo('body');

var imRoot = $("#im-menu");
var buddies = $("#buddies");
imRoot.click(function(){
buddies.toggle();
imRoot.blur();
return( false );
});
$("#exitlist").click(function(){
buddies.toggle();
imRoot.blur();
return( false );
});
$(document).click(function( event ){
if (buddies.is( ":visible" ) && !$( event.target ).closest( "#buddies" ).size()){
buddies.hide();
}
});
$(function FL(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'config/receive_buddylist.php',
    cache: 'false',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){    
        onlineNumber = buddylistreceived = 0;
        data && $.each(data, function(i, e){
            if (i == "buddylist") {
                buddylistreceived = 1;
                totalFriendsNumber = onlineNumber = 0;
                $.each(e, function (l, f) {
                    if(f.id != null){
                        longname = f.n.length > 16 ? f.n.substr(0, 16) + "..." : f.n;
                        $('#myonlinefavs').append('<li>' + longname + '</li>');
                    }
                    if(f.s == '0') onlineNumber++;
                    totalFriendsNumber++;                           
                });
            }
        });
        R = onlineNumber;
        if (R > 0){
            $('#friendsonline').html(onlineNumber);
        } else {
            $('#myonlinefavs').html('No favorites online.');
            $('#friendsonline').html('0');
        }
    }
});
Z = setTimeout(function () {
    FL()
}, 1000)

});


});
```

Comment: Why are you using `post` instead of just [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)?

Comment: From my understand `$.getJSON` is just a shorter way of doing `post`

Comment: You aren't sending any data, so `GET` would be more appropriate than `POST`, and yes, `$.getJSON` is a shorter way of doing what you are doing, so he is wondering why you are using the more complicated way.

Comment: Oh ok, I had never really read up on it. Only been working with jquery for about a little over a month now, but I have now switched it to `$.getJSON` which does save on coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your `$.each` function that appends list items to the `myonlinefavs` element, you should clear the list, like this: `$('#myonlinefavs').html("")`.

Comment: [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty) will also work, and the intent of the code is even clearer.

Comment: @Matt Cool! I didn't know about that function. I'll definitely use that in the future.